# Why am I being told that my 'then' and 'else' expressions are not the same type?

Tags: string, if-statement, type-conversion, cognos

I used an if-then-else statement to define a variable in a query join on IBM Cognos Report Studio 10.2.2. In the 'then' clause, I use the hard-coded string 'Not reportable'. For the 'else' clause, I use the variable [Generational Distribution], which is defined elsewhere in the query join, and is a string-valued variable from one of the joining query. I would therefore expect that the 'then' and 'else' clauses are both string-valued.

However, when I run, I get the following error:

```
OP-ERR-0206 Unsupported 'if' expression dataItem = "Generation Reportable." The 'then'
(expression = "'Not reportable'") and 'else' (expression = "[Generational Distribution]")
clauses must have the same data type.
```

The details begin:

```
RSV-SRV-0042 Trace back:RSReportService.cpp(724): QFException: CCL_CAUGHT:
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the actual expression you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I tried fixing the problem by changing the else clause to trim(cast([Generational Distribution],char(15))). The report now runs fine, but something else strange happens. The item appears as 'Boomers' for every case where the 'if' clause is false, while there are also 'Millennials' and 'Gen X' generations.